Introductory Resources on Numerical Methods for PDEs with Convergence Analysis
I'm looking for an introductory book or online lecture notes on numerical methods for PDEs, specifically focusing on finite difference schemes for the Laplace, heat, and wave equations, with a rigorous convergence and stability analysis at the graduate level. Any recommendations for resources that cover stability, consistency, and convergence would be greatly appreciated!

I use R. J. LeVeque's textbook (draft version freely on his web) for my graduate numerical methods class (focusing on FDM): https://faculty.washington.edu/rjl/fdmbook
For a more functional analytical take I use Long Chen's notes: https://www.math.uci.edu/~chenlong/lectures.html
